# Python Calls EXE from a different directory than the Python Script

Tags: python

I have a Python script that calls an EXE which in turns accesses and converts HTML/CSS/JS files to PDF. Importantly, all CSS and JS references in the HTML are relative paths as this script is expected to be accessed on different computers.

The Python script looks like this:

```py
file_directory = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PATH_TO_EXE = os.path.join(file_directory, 'html-to-pdf.exe')

def convertHTML(*args):

    if not os.path.isfile(PATH_TO_EXE):
        raise FileNotFoundError("ERROR MESSAGE")

    call_args = f'\"{PATH_TO_EXE}\" \"' + '\" \"'.join(args) + '\"'
    subprocess.call(call_args)
```

The script is stored in a subdirectory of the root directory which is a GitHub repository.

If I run this script in VSCode by opening the subdirectory where the script is stored, everything works as intended, all CSS and JS is loaded since their relative paths are within the subdirectory.

However, if I am to open up the root directory in VSCode (which is normal for opening a GitHub repo) and run the script, the CSS and JS is not loaded because I suspect it is unable to find the CSS and JS because the HTML is now loaded in the root directory.

I imagine there is a way to work this out with the HTML, and certainly with the EXE (written in C#) to avoid this issue but I would rather deal with it in Python since that seems to be the inconsistency.

Can I either force the Python script to run within the same directory that it is stored or ensure it calls the function from the proper location?

I can run in the command line from any directory `"C:/path/to/exe" "source.html" "output.pdf"` and it WILL work properly since the HTML is loaded in the correct place.

Comment: Aside: Don't concatenate strings to make the command argument to `subprocess.call()`. Use the list format.

Comment: If you want to find exe file relative to the directory where py file is, then do that. Don't calculate path relative to cwd and then expect the py file to be in cwd.

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(__file__)`? It seems like this must have something to do with the way VS Code is running the script, and it's not getting set as expected.

Comment: @zvone sorry, I meant to change the code to say file_directory in lieu of cwd but I get the path of the file which is not the cwd and then join that to the exe name which gives me the absolute path of the exe. Python seems to be executing it from a different directory than where the exe and script is stored.

Comment: @Barmar print(\_\_file\_\_) returns the path of the file within the subdirectory

Comment: If it's returning the correct path, I don't see why the rest is failing. It shouldn't matter where it's executing it from if it uses an absolute pathname for `PATH_TO_EXE`.

Comment: Mind, if you want to control the working directory given to the subprocess to pass something distinct of the default (of the parent process's working directory), you can do that; see the `cwd` argument to the `subprocess.Popen`-family functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I worked out to ensure the correct directory is being used is to change to the directory of the file.

The code looks as follows:

```py
# get file directory
file_directory = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# get path to exe
PATH_TO_EXE = os.path.join(file_directory, 'html-to-pdf.exe')

# change working directory if it is different than the file directory
if os.getcwd() != file_directory:
    os.chdir(file_directory)

def convertHTML(input, output):
    # check if the exe exists
    if not os.path.isfile(PATH_TO_EXE):
        raise FileNotFoundError("ERROR")

    # call the exe with the args
    subprocess.call([PATH_TO_EXE, input, output])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convertHTML('source.html', 'output.pdf')
```